# Why is $\mathbb Z$ a $\mathbb Z[\pi]-$module?

Tags: algebraic-topology, modules, homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups

Let $X$ be a topological space with fundamental group $\pi_1X:=\pi$. I read that to recover the cellular homology of $X$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$ from the homology of $X$ with local coefficients in a $\mathbb Z[\pi]-$module $A$ we just take $A$ to be $\mathbb Z$. My problem is how to see $\mathbb Z$ as a  $\mathbb Z[\pi]-$module ? Thank you for your help ?

Comment: Hint: consider the trivial $\pi$-action on $\mathbb Z$

Comment: @Wojowu Are you saying that any ring $R$ is an $S-$module where the ring $S$ acts on $R$ trivially ?

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. In general, for a group ring $\mathbb Z[G]$, an $\mathbb Z[G]$-module is the same thing as an abelian group together with an action of $G$ by automorphisms. It might be enlightening for you to try and prove that.

Comment: @Wojowu Are you saying that any group $A$ is a $\mathbb Z[G]-$module for any group $G$ ? because we always have a trivial action of  $G$ on $A$..

Comment: Yes, except that we need $A$ to be an *abelian* group, otherwise it is not a $\mathbb Z$-module.

Comment: @Wojowu the trivial action of a group $G$ on an abelian group $A$ does not respect distributivity to see $A$ as a $\mathbb Z[G]$ structure, indeed, $(g_1+g_2)a=a \not = g_1a+g_2a=a+a=2a$

Comment: In this action, only elements of $G$ are guaranteed to act as identity. $g_1+g_2$ is *not* an element of $G$, it's a linear combibation of such.

Comment: what if $G$ is abelian, then $g_1+g_2$ is indeed an element of $G$..

Comment: Unless you write $G$ multiplicatively, you are going to confuse yourself like that. If you insist on additive notation, then you have to distinguish between two addition operators - one is the group operation, the other is the addition within the group ring.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: More generally, for any ring $R$ with (two-sided) ideal $I$, there's a natural left and a natural right $R$-module structure on $R/I$.

Hint 2: More generally, if there is a homomorphism of rings $R\rightarrow S$, such that the image of $R$ is contained in the centre of $S$, every $S$-module can be given the structure of an $R$-module via that homomorphism.

Comment: $R$ needn't be commutative here.

Comment: @Wojowu: I'm aware of generalisations to left / right module structures in noncommutative settings, but I thought it's not what the OP needs right now.

Comment: What I'm saying is that your hint doesn't answer the question, because the situation in the question isn't covered by your answer.

Comment: @Wojowu: I see now, sorry. Edited.